# What is the numerical value of $(-3)^{\pi}$

Tags: numerical-methods, pi

As the title suggest what is the numerical value of $(-3)^{\pi}$?

could we derive an answer using numerical analysis something along the lines of well if its basically $(-3) \cdot(-3) \cdot (-3) \cdot(-3)^{\pi-3}$?

Comment: The numerical value is exactly $\;(-3)^\pi\;$ ...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please see this handy [formatting reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to typeset math.

Comment: @Théophile thanks man i wanted to just didnt know how!.

Comment: Hint: it won't be a real number.  Try $(-1)^x$

Comment: @karakfa can you elaborate more?>

Comment: See: [Non-integer exponents of negative numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794897/non-integer-exponents-of-negative-numbers)

Comment: $$(-3)^{\pi}=e^{\pi \ln (-3)}=e^{\pi \cdot (\ln 3+\mathrm i\pi)}=e^{\pi \ln 3}\cdot e^{\mathrm i \pi^2}$$

Comment: The imaginary part is due to  $(-1)^x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematicians generally define powers of negative real numbers using [the principal value of the complex logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Definition_of_principal_value), that is

$$(-3)^\pi:= e^{\pi\ln(-3)}=e^{\pi(\ln|-3|+i\arg(-3))}=e^{\pi\ln 3+i\pi^2}=3^\pi\cdot e^{i\pi^2}$$

where $e^{i\pi^2}$ is the complex number defined by a vector on the complex plane of length $1$ such that the angle with the real line is $\pi^2$, that is

$$e^{i\pi^2}=\cos\pi^2+i\sin\pi^2$$

With WolframAlpha I get this numerical approximation:

$$(-3)^\pi\approx -28.47456 -i\, 13.57354$$

Comment: $\cos \pi^2 \approx  \frac12(\pi*(\pi-3))^2-1$